# Importing python modules from folders

Tags: python-3.x

So, I am having the following structure in my python package:

```
./main.py
__init__.py
./mymods/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
```

my module a.py imports module b:

```
import b
```

Now, I want to import module a from main but when I do I get the following:

```
import mymods.a

ImportError: No module named 'b'
```

I googled but I couldn't find a solution to this particular problem.
Any good samaritan who knows how to do this?

p.s. I would prefer not to have to import the module b explicitly from main, if that is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `mymods` into a package.
This can be done simply by creating an empty `__init__.py` file in the directory.

```
➜ tree
.
├── main.py
└── mymods
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── a.py
    └── b.py

1 directory, 4 files
➜ cat main.py
import mymods.a

print 'printing from main'
➜ cat mymods/a.py
from . import b

print 'printing from a'

➜ cat mymods/b.py
print 'printing from b

➜ python main.py
printing from b
printing from a
printing from main
```

For Python 3, change the `import b` to `from . import b`.

Comment: I edited it to include how I laid out the project, and what is in the source files. How does yours differ ?

Comment: Ah, it works with python 2 but not 3.. and I was running python 3. Since I do need to run py3, do you know what the solution might be?

Comment: For Py3, change the import to `from . import b`. That is compatible with Python 2.7.

Comment: Aah, there we go. Thank you so much, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to add empty  `__init__.py` file into each folder within your py project.

See more on [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)